# Wrong format of JSON from [String: Any]

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to set up a server on Heroku Node.js and set route for POST method. 
This is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(bodyParser.raw());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/song',  (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body);
  response.send(request.body);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I create an easy ios app to send a POST request to my local Heroku.

```
@objc func sendPost() {
        guard let url = URL.init(string: "http://localhost:5000/song") as URL? else {
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        let text : [String: Any] = ["name": "test Name",
                    "artist": "test Artist",
                    "album": "test Album"]

        let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: text)

        request.httpBody = data!
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, resp, error) in
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print(responseJSON!)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

About an issue, when I logged request.body on Node.js I got the wrong JSON:
**{ '{"album":"test Album","name":"test Name","artist":"test Artist"}': '' }** 
I mean, that my dictionary becomes a key for empty value. Why this happens?

Update: 
The problem is in converting Dictionary to Data by JSONSerializtaion.

```
let text : [String: Any] = ["name": "Olol",
                    "artist": "OMG",
                    "album": "nonon"]
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: text)
print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

In logs:

```
{
    "{\"album\":\"nonon\",\"name\":\"Olol\",\"artist\":\"OMG\"}" = "";
}
```

Why all my data becomes a key for an empty value?

Comment: If you do `let str = String(data:request.httpBody encoding:.utf8)` (in pseudo code), and print it, it should be find. So the issue should be on your server part.

Comment: @Larme I found a problem. Look please at the end of question

Comment: I tried your code in a playground and it prints `{"album":"nonon","name":"Olol","artist":"OMG"}`

Comment: Could you put the real code on how you construct `text`? Because it shouldn't give you that result. Try the exact code you pasted here, just the `text` and `data` and you'd see it shouldn't produce that.